# Adding firebase firestore object react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to add a a firebase obejct to the firestore using the method

```
db.collection('dogs').doc(this.props.dog.dogId).update({
 swipes: {
 [card.dogId]: true
      }
    })
```

however this simply replaces the previous value while I want to add multiple values to the swipes object.
I then tried the method

```
db.collection('dogs').doc(this.props.dog.dogId).update({
 swipes: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(card.dogId)

    })
```

however this doesn't allow me to add a swipe value to it. 
How do I add multiple cards Ids without replacing each other

I would like to add the value card

```
swipes: {
 [card.dogId]: true
}
```

without replacing the previous value

Comment: At first glance the code seems correct. Can you show a screenshot of the document (in the console) before running the update, and a screenshot after it, so that we can see what happens?

Comment: What part of the code seems correct to you the first method or the second method?

Comment: The first code will replace whatever you have in `swipes` with whatever you specify in the call. The second code should merge the value in `card.dogId` with the existing values in `swipes`, if it's not in there yet.

Comment: The second method does add card.dogId to the swipes however Id like to add [card.dogId]: true, how do I do that with the second mehtod? it complains whenever I put anything more than card.dogId

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you do that then?

Comment: Edit it to show what? the second method in the questions adds each card.dogId to the db I'd like to however not just add card.dogId but to add card.dogId:true

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I edited the question best way I could

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a nested field to true, you can do so with:

```
let values = { swipes: {} };
values.swipes[card.docId] = true
db.collection('dogs').doc(this.props.dog.dogId).update(values)
```

Comment: when it updates it replaces the value that was there before, how do I update while keeping all the values from before, simply appending to the values already there